# How can I view non-English file names in an App Service Console?

Tags: azure

I am looking at a `dir` listing in an App Service Console. International file names look like this:
[image]

I know that to be a name using Cyrillic characters (our applications can handle those files without problems). Is there any way to see it?

Comment: Sure. You have to set the console encoding to UTF8 and use a font with those Cyrillic chars.

Comment: @JesúsÁngel it's the App Service Console. I can't change the font. I tried CHCP but nothing changed.